# IE weird scrolling issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have some html code as follows:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="items">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and css as such:

```
#wrapper {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
}

#items {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:1000px;
  height:200px;
}

#items .item {
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
}
```

By using jQuery's animate function I animate the wrapper layer when going left or right so that I can see all the items within the items layer.  As it gets to the end I stop the animation, reset the scrollLeft position of the items layer and continue the animation thus generating a continuous effect.

In Firefox and Chrome works without a glitch.  In IE I get a problem when I do the following:

When I scroll right for a few pixels and then scroll left I get two animations, the first is really quick and the second is as it should behave.

Hope this makes sense.

Has anybody experienced this before?

Steve

Comment: I did not experience this before, but my intuition tells me that this is a performance-related problem. IE is probably too slow at doing this, so that we can see it. Other browsers do those changes that fast that we cannot see it.

Comment: What style property are you animating?

Comment: @Pointy I animate as follows: 

$("#wrapper").animate({scrollLeft:x},duration);

I also reset the position by $("#wrapper").scrollLeft(x);

Comment: Hmm.  Well, I'm guessing here (which is kind-of a requirement for IE weirdness), but I might try animating "marginLeft" instead of "scrollLeft".